# Google app engine, setup domain showing This host is possibly misconfigured

Tags: php, google-app-engine

I have app engine php app, and configure it with google app.
and add CNAME entries to `ghs.googlehosted.com.` for `*`, `www`.
and now live site showing that

> This host is possibly misconfigured. If you own this domain, please consult this FAQ.

in apps's ServiceSettings page it's showing activated  service for that app engine project.

Comment: This error message appears to relate to Googles PageSpeed Service, are you using this? (https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/service). If so have you seen these articles?  https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/service/faq#whymisconfigured and https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/service/faq#hostedongoogle

Comment: thanks for remind me.. very long time ago we configred that domain with pagespeed server too...now deleted that project.. so lets wait for next few days.

Comment: As you are now using App Engine, you can turn PageSpeed on within the admin console (which will be free from 1st April following their price change announcements earlier this week).

Answer (score 1):

This error message appears to relate to using Googles PageSpeed Service (developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/service) on a site hosted on App Engine which is not supported (App Engine has its own PageSpeed service built in).

More info: https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/service/faq#hostedongoogle